# Can I use CircleCI with other OS than Ubuntu?

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci

Is it possible to use CircleCI with other OS than Ubuntu? I can't find an answer in the documentation.

Particularly I would like to use Debian 7.8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a Docker image of Debian 7.8 inside your build, but it's not possible at this time to replace the base image of the build VM.

Comment: Confirmed on official support.