# What Linux version does CircleCI use? Can it be modified?

Tags: linux, continuous-integration, circleci

We've connected our node.js app with CircleCI. I understand how to control which services are running on the machine, but not how to identify the OS version, or whether there's a way to change it, so that the unit tests will run on the same OS version as the production machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per the documentation, CircleCI currently uses Ubuntu 12.04.](https://circleci.com/docs/environment)

You can check for yourself by [running a build with ssh enabled](https://circleci.com/docs/ssh-build) and examining one of the build instances:

```
$ ssh -p 64538 ubuntu@54.205.50.104 cat /etc/os-release                   
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.04.5 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)"
VERSION_ID="12.04"
```

The question of whether you can use a different OS has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591836/can-i-use-circleci-with-other-os-than-ubuntu). The answer is that you can use a Docker image with a different OS, but you can't replace the build container's base OS.

Comment: Thanks, actually there's another way I used to detect the OS version - the same command can be put in the circle.yml file, and then you can get the info starting the next build.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to detect OS version, other than via ssh, is adding the same command to the circle.yml file. For example:

```
machine:
  pre:
    - cat /etc/os-release
```

That way, the OS version will show in the log of every build.